# Disable ssh password authentication programmaticaly

Tags: ssh, login, password

I am provisioning a machine using [`packer`](https://www.packer.io/).

The tool offers shell provisioning functionality so I am able to run whatever shell commands I want.

I would like to disable `ssh` password login.

Is there a way to do this via a command, rather than ending up writing pattern and line mathing `sed`s for `/etc/sshd_config` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to disable password authentication via the command-line. Simply use the `-o` flag when running the daemon: `sshd -o "PasswordAuthentication no"`

Comment: Isn't it `sshd -o "PasswordAuthentication no"`? I think there is a reduntand whitespace in your command

Comment: Oops, yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

SSH has support for keys. If you set up private and public keys there is no need to use a password.

This means you are not disabling the password login but you are just using a different method to authenticate against the machine.